# How to add option to change view type to days using JavaScript Calendar (in my Angular APP)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-5

Hello community I am using the fullcalendar of  https://fullcalendar.io/ (version 5) in my angular 9 application.

I have seen that the calendar has these options to change the view type.

[image]

But I don't understand how to enable those options in my application
I currently have this
[image]

Para instalar es

I have installed the modules

```
npm install --save @fullcalendar/angular
npm install --save  @fullcalendar/daygrid
npm i @fullcalendar/interaction
```

I have imported it to the module where you used it

```
// calendar
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  dayGridPlugin,
  interactionPlugin
]);

and I've created a component called organizer to use it, in which I have the following code

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CalendarOptions } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-skechuler',
      templateUrl: './skechuler.component.html',
      styles: [
      ]
    })
    export class SkechulerComponent implements OnInit {
    
      calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // bind is important!
        events: [
          { title: 'event 1', date: '2020-06-27' },
          { title: 'event 2', date: '2020-06-30' }
        ]
      };
      handleDateClick(arg: any) {
        alert('date: ' + arg.dateStr);
      }
    
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    }
```

and its html

```
<full-calendar #calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>


but i don't understand how to activate the above mentioned function to access this view:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing headerToolbar option.

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
```

Comment: Thanks bro, by the way do you know how to change the lange of the full-calendar?

Comment: did you mean range ? i apologize. I did not get your question.